# Eager-loading association count with Arel (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, eager-loading, arel

Simple task: given that an article has many comments, be able to display in a long list of articles how many comments each article has. I'm trying to work out how to preload this data with Arel.

The "Complex Aggregations" section of the [README](http://github.com/rails/arel/blob/master/README.markdown) file seems to discuss that type of situation, but it doesn't exactly offer sample code, nor does it offer a way to do it in two queries instead of one joined query, which is worse for performance.

Given the following:

```
class Article
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :article
end
```

How can I preload for an article set how many comments each has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something nasty using SQL like:

```
default_scope :select => 'articles.*, (select count(comments.id) from comments where comments.article_id = articles.id) as count_comments'
```

and then you would have access to Article.first.count_comments.

Another (nicer) method to do it is to use the 'counter_cache' feature/option from [belongs_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001835) association.

Comment: Silly me was in a rush and forgot about caching it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Can't you use counter cache for this?

```
belongs_to :article, :counter_cache => true
```

You also need to have a migration that adds the column comments_count

Comment: I recently had problems in production using counter_cache with single table inheritance and had to roll my own